# How to define a class in view.py with no queryset and serializers

Tags: django

```
views.py
class SendEmail(ListAPIView):
        .....

urls.py
 path('api/sendemail/', views.SendEmail.as_view(), name='sendemail')
```

I am trying write a backend api to send emails. The problem is that I do not need queryset and serializer in this Sendemail class. But It will raise errors if there is no queryset and selializer in the class. Can someone show me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need those, why are you declaring it as a ListAPIView? In fact it sounds like it shouldn't be an API view at all. Just use Django's basic View class.